# Finding Largest And Smallest Number With UserInput ,c++

Tags: c++, function

im trying to create a function which is called in the main function to allow the user to input any amount of numbers until '0' is entered. with this function giving the number of values entered and the sum of these values along with the highest and lowest numbers entered.

okay so assuming all numbers entered are integers... the output for SmallestNum is always incorrect... ive spent days trying to solve this problem and feel im prolly overlooking or missing something out...

what am i missing out?

```cpp
int MaxMin_Int(int& sum,int& count,int& LargestNum,int& SmallestNum)
{
    int num;
    
    do{
        cout<< "Enter Number (Press 0 to Exit): ";
        cin>>num;
        
        sum = sum + num;
        count++;                        //incerement count...

        
        if ( num > LargestNum)          // Store Largest number in variable LargestNum
            LargestNum = num;
        else if ( num > SmallestNum && num < LargestNum )
            SmallestNum = num;          //Store Smallest number in SmallestNum varaible
            
        

    }while(num != 0);
        count--;
                                
    

    
    return sum,count,LargestNum,SmallestNum;
}

int main(){
    
    //decleration of static variables
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int LargestNum = 0;
    int SmallestNum = 1;
    
    //Loop that breaks Once User Enters '0'
    
    // Output the sum of numbers and number of numbers entered before program was executed.
    //Sum_int(count,sum);

    MaxMin_Int(sum,count,LargestNum,SmallestNum);
    
    cout<<"\n\n"<<count<<" Values Were Entered"<<endl;
    cout<<"With a sum of: "<<sum<<endl<<endl;
    
    // Out put Highest And Lowest Numbers
    
    
    cout<<"Largest Number Entered: "<< LargestNum <<endl;
    cout<<"Smallest Number Entered: "<< SmallestNum <<endl;
    
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (num < SmallestNum)`?

Comment: @rabbid76 thank you for the answer.. however ive tried to use if (num < SmallestNum) it then takes 0 as the lowest number ... is there any other way i can store the lowest number other the '0' ..

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think anyone understands what you're talking about. Isn't 0 the lowest number? After the first input (`count == 0`) you have to set `LargestNum` and `SmallestNum `.

Comment: sorry about that and thank you very much for your answer.. it makes much sense now :)

Comment: What did you mean by `return sum,count,LargestNum,SmallestNum;` and how does it correspond to the declared function's return type of `int`...?

Answer (score 1):

You should test `if ( num < SmallestNum)`.

Additionally reconsider the initial value for `SmallestNum`. What happens if the input is `7 3 12`? All numbers are greater than `1` so none will be assigned to `SmallestNum` and the output will be `1` even though there was no `1` in the user's input.

Comment: noted and really appreciated for the time taken to reply to my question.. will implement changes and see how it goes. ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues. After the first input (`count == 0`) you have to set `LargestNum` and `SmallestNum` . If the exit criteria is 0, ignore 0. The smallest number is detected with the condition `if (num < SmallestNum)`. The arguments are passed by reference. No return value is required.

```cpp
void MaxMin_Int(int& sum, int& count, int& LargestNum, int& SmallestNum)
{
    int num;
    
    sum = count = LargestNum = SmallestNum = 0;
    do {
        cout << "Enter Number (Press 0 to Exit): ";
        cin >> num;
        
        if (num != 0)
        {
            if (count == 0)
                LargestNum = SmallestNum = num;
            else if (num > LargestNum) 
                LargestNum = num;
            else if (num < SmallestNum)
                SmallestNum = num;   

            sum += num;
            count++;   
        }
    } while (num != 0);
}
```